# solve the equation $f(x)=(x^2-3)^4+2x^4-12x^2+10$

Tags: calculus

I want to solve this equation and find x:
$$f(x)=(x^2-3)^4+2x^4-12x^2+10$$

What I know is basical rules of solvin quadratic equations and I know \delta and etc.
I want to solve it  using by means of:
$$(az^4)+(bz^2)+c=0$$
And then we will have
 $$z^2=y$$
And slove it using y and then square root for y.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(x^2-3)^4+2x^4-12x^2+10=(x^2-3)^4+2(x^2-3)^2-8$

Comment: Thanks Lee now i hope bests fot you

Comment: @Mrinvisible if this answer solved your problem then please accept it, its the green tick